# how would I know if the word being read by fgets is in a new line?

Tags: c, file, fgets

I'm reading a program in C and I want to locate the new line, but i don't know how.

I'm reading the text file like this:

```
    while(!feof(fp)){
         fgets(buffer, 4, fp);
    }
```

and my text file is like this:

```
C01 RDA ALB NAC EDF
C02 MCA EDF SLF ADG
```

how would I know if the word being read by fgets is in a new line??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to call `feof()` before doing I/O, that's simply not how it works.

If you're that interested in the location of each newline, read the file character by character instead, using `fgetc()`. Then parse the character stream into words. This will make it trivial to notice when a newline comes along.

Comment: how can i parse it into words?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to get three characters at a time (which is what you get for `size` 4, because `fgets` reads one less than `size` characters), thus getting the pieces

`C01`  `RD` `A A` `LB`  `NAC`  `ED` `F¶` `C02`  `MC` `A E` `DF`  `SLF`  `AD` `G¶`

(`¶` denoting newline)? I don't think so, but rather you want four characters at a time and trim the word delimiters.

```
char buffer[5];
char newline = 1;
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp))
{
    if (newline) puts("new line:");
    newline = buffer[3] == '\n';
    buffer[3] = '\0';
    puts(buffer);
}
```